# merge to set default values, but potentially expensive functions

Tags: clojure

An idiomatic way to set default values in clojure is with merge:

```
;; `merge` can be used to support the setting of default values
(merge {:foo "foo-default" :bar "bar-default"} 
       {:foo "custom-value"})
;;=> {:foo "custom-value" :bar "bar-default"}
```

In reality however, often the default values are not simple constants but function calls. Obviously, I'd like to avoid calling the function if it's not going to be used.

So far I'm doing something like:

```
(defn ensure-uuid [msg]
  (if (:uuid msg)
    msg
    (assoc msg :uuid (random-uuid))))
```

and apply my `ensure-*` functions like `(-> msg ensure-uuid ensure-xyz)`.

What would be a more idiomatic way to do this? I'm thinking something like:

```
(merge-macro {:foo {:bar (expensive-func)} :xyz (other-fn)} my-map)

(associf my-map
  [:foo :bar] (expensive-func)
  :xyz (other-fn))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just adapted the `condp` macros and wrote the following:

```
(defmacro assoc-if-nil
  "Takes a map as the first argument and a succession of key value pairs that
  are used to set the key to value if the key of the map is nil. The value part
  is only evaluated if the key is nil (thus different semantics to (merge)).
  Example:
  (assoc-if-nil {:a {:b :set}}
    [:a :b] :non-def
    [:a :c] :non-def
    :d :non-def)
  ;; =>{:a {:b :set, :c :non-def}, :d :non-def}"
  [m & clauses]
  (assert (even? (count clauses)))
  (let [g (gensym)
        get-fn   (fn[kork] (if (vector? kork) `get-in   `get))
        assoc-fn (fn[kork] (if (vector? kork) `assoc-in `assoc))
        pstep (fn [[kork v]] `(if-not (~(get-fn kork) ~g ~kork)
                                (~(assoc-fn kork) ~g ~kork ~v)
                                ~g))]
    `(let [~g ~m ;; avoid double evaluation
           ~@(interleave (repeat g) (map pstep (partition 2 clauses)))]
       ~g)))
```

Which expands to:

```
(macroexpand-1 '
(assoc-if-nil m
              [:a :b] :nested
              :d :just-key))

(clojure.core/let
 [G__15391     m
  G__15391
  (clojure.core/if-not
   (clojure.core/get-in G__15391 [:a :b])
   (clojure.core/assoc-in G__15391 [:a :b] :nested)
   G__15391)
  G__15391
  (clojure.core/if-not
   (clojure.core/get G__15391 :d)
   (clojure.core/assoc G__15391 :d :just-key)
   G__15391)]
 G__15391)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`delay`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay) combined with [`force`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/force).

You can then merge your defaults like

```
(merge {:foo "foo-default" :bar "bar-default" :uuid (delay (random-uuid))}
       {:foo "custom-value" :uuid "abc"})
```

and access values using

```
(force (:foo ...))
```

or

```
(force (:uuid ...))
```

`random-uuid` will then only be called when you actually need the value (and only the first time).

You can wrap the call to `force` in a `get-value` function, or something like that.

Comment: That's a good idea but suffers from then calling `force` throughout your application code which I'd like to avoid. I wrote a macro which works very well for my use case. Cheers & Thanks

Comment: Good. Different semantics, though - your solution evaluates if no value is provided in the map, with delay it only evaluates if the value ends up being used.